# hsqldb: do I have to ORDER BY to ensure consistent selection order?

Tags: indexing, hsqldb

I have a table containing samples. The inserted samples are already naturally ordered by the timestamp.

My question is this - when I SELECT from the table do I have to use the ORDER BY clause to ensure the fetched samples are ordered by the timestamp?

Comment: Use order by , just to be on the safer side .

Comment: I am still interested to know whether it is necessary.

Comment: I didn't find it necessary . But the Order by clause can significantly hamper the performance if the number of records are large . HSQLDB doesn't make effective usage of Indexes , that's from my experience .

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11948/when-is-a-result-returned-deterministic-and-when-not

Comment: @noob: but if you need to have the rows in a specific order, there is no other way to guarantee this order. If you don't need them sorted (or don't care), then `order by` should not be used (because very often it will make the query slower).

Comment: If an HSQLDB table T has a column C as primary key, or has any index on that column, SELECT FROM T ORDER BY C USING INDEX will return ordered rows without extra ORDER BY processing.

Comment: @fredt - your comment deserves to be a reply, I would like to +1 it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows in a relation database are ***NOT*** sorted (Picture them as balls in a basket. Which one is the "first"?)

The **only** way (really, the *only*) to get a consistently sorted result is to use `ORDER BY`.

You cannot rely on side effects of joins, `group by`. `UNION`, index retrieval or similar operators. They will never guarantee an order. The DBMS is free to choose to return the rows in whatever order it thinks is the fastest unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @mark: that depends. I'd say most of the time sorting on the server might be more efficient.

Comment: @mark: why don't you try? There isn't a definite answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

If an HSQLDB table T has a column C as primary key, or has any index on that column,

```
SELECT FROM T ORDER BY C
```

will return ordered rows without extra ORDER BY processing.

If there is a condition on the select, which uses an index on a different column, you can still force the use of the index for ORDER BY:

```
SELECT FROM T WHERE <some condition> ORDER BY C USING INDEX
```

But in this case, you should only use USING INDEX if most of the rows of the table will be returned. Otherwise it is better to leave the engine use the other index to reduce the table scan time.

USING INDEX is ignored if there is no index to use for ORDER BY.